# Fetching a JSON via JSP to JS

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp, servlets

I'm having some trouble getting a JSON String from my servlet, throu my JSP page to my JavaScript and imported into a Vakata/JStree.

This how my current code looks like.

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Du är nu i DoGet MarketDataServlet");

    TreeBranchStringBuilder tbsb = new TreeBranchStringBuilder();       
    request.setAttribute("marketgrouplistJSONString", tbsb.getTreeBranchString(mm.getAllMarketgroups(), im.getAllItems()));
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/marketdata.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

JSP/HTML:

```
<div id="market_tree_branches">
</div>

<div id="hidden"><%= request.getAttribute("marketgrouplistJSONString") %></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var marketnitemsString = $("#hidden").text();
console.log(marketnitemsString)
$('#market_tree_branches').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : marketnitemsString
    }
});
```

String that's generated from my JSP looks like:

```
[{"id":2,"text":"Blueprints","parent":"#"},{"id":204,"text":"Ships","parent":"2"},{"id":209,"text":"Ship Equipment","parent":"2"},{"id":211,"text":"Ammunition \u0026 Charges","parent":"2"},{"id":357,"text":"Drones","parent":"2"},{"id":943,"text":"Ship Modifications","parent":"2"},{"id":1041,"text":"Manufacture \u0026 Research","parent":"2"},{"id":1338,"text":"Structures","parent":"2"},{"id":9,"text":"Ship Equipment","parent":"#"},{"id":10,"text":"Turrets \u0026 Bays","parent":"9"}]
```

This is the error i'm getting in my Chrome Console Log:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
[{"id":2,"text":"Blueprints","parent":"#"},{"id":204,"text":"Ships","parent":"2"},{"id":209,"text":"Ship Equipment","parent":"2"},{"id":211,"text":"Ammunition \u0026 Charges","parent":"2"}, ........
```

I'm guessing that something during the process of sending it from the JSP/HTML to the JavaScript variable goes wrong but i cant figure out what, since the JStree cant read it as a variable. If i however copy/paste the entire string from the HTML into the 'data': it works fine.

Comment: Not too familiar with jsTree, but you might have to parse the JSON to a JS object before loading it in. Also, why do you use a hidden field instead of a plain AJAX call? That alone may solve your problem.

Comment: Tried the JSON.parse() it, but doesnt help. The JStree accepts 2 ways of inputs as i understood it 
1. JSON/Arrays which follow the a structure where the parents needs to know it's children in the JSON/Array.

2. With the string method it is however possible to do it the way our relationship is done from the DB. With Children knowing their parent, hence the "parent": attrib.

Comment: Ok, after alot of more googling and finally some more trial and error it seems like JSON.parse(marketnitemsString) actually works. I'm 100% sure i tried it a few times but it didnt. It is however possible i might have tried it only with my full string and not my small test string. Because when i try with that one it all goes to hell.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would to be use an AJAX call from the JavasScript code directly to the servlet. There's absolutely no reason to have the JSP get in the middle there. You can just do something like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Du är nu i DoGet MarketDataServlet");

    TreeBranchStringBuilder tbsb = new TreeBranchStringBuilder();       
    String json = bsb.getTreeBranchString(mm.getAllMarketgroups(), im.getAllItems());
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().println(json);
}
```

For the JavaScript side, it depends entirely on what JavaScript framework you want to use. [JQuery is the easiest starting point](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this.

Comment: Ok, thank you was considering that option. But figured i would ask here first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have to pass through a hidden element:

```
var marketnitemsString = <%= request.getAttribute("marketgrouplistJSONString") %>;
$('#market_tree_branches').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : marketnitemsString
    }
});
```

Since the `<% %>` is executed before the js is parsed, the text it produces is then interpreted as standard JS by the client and as long as it is semantically correct, it will do what's supposed to (store an array in the variable).

This is pretty much similar to code that I actually use so I'm fairly sure it works even if I cannot test it at the moment.

Also, if your data is an array, I'm not sure that the core.data element could accept it in form of a string:

http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.core.data

so that could be the origin of the problem with your code.

Comment: My JavaScript is in a separate file, and at least i've been told there is no way to use the <% %> JSP tags in a file.js.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You could still declare the var as shown in your main HTML and then use it in a JS *included later* by a <script> tag.